# Typo in change under review notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, typographical-error

Just noticed this grammatical error in the change-under-review notification within SO Documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix going out in the next build. Thanks!

Comment: I think you meant, "Fix is be out..." (kudos on the turnaround time here!)

Comment: Wow, for sure, impressive! Thanks for the great work, Adam.